# Hosting ASP.net web service in web server

Tags: asp.net, service, web

I have developed an ASP.net web service, how to host this service on monthly pay web server, because most of the web server providers hosting only asp.net web sites.

Comment: WCF service or traditional asmx?

Answer (score 2):

1. Host your web service in IIS same as you host an asp.net website.
2. Go to web.config of your web service.
3. Change the endpoint address to "localhost:port_number/webservice_aliasname/service_name.svc"

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I hosted my web service in my local IIS and tested, its working fine inside my LAN network. But I just want to host my web service (asmx) in any monthly pay web server to call methods from outside of my LAN network. I want to know am I want host the web service in web server same like asp.net website or are there any other procedures to follow for web service hosting

Comment: @PrasadMari : Hosting is same as you host an asp.net website. And in the monthly pay web server also, you have to host it in IIS same as you hosted in your local IIS.